# Waking up a sleeping thread - interrupt() versus "splitting" the sleep into multiple sleeps

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sleep

This requirement came up in my Android app, but it applies to Java in general. My app "does something" every few seconds. I have implemented this as follows (just relevant snippets - not a complete code):

**Snippet1:**

```
public class PeriodicTask {

    private boolean running = true;
    private int interval = 5;

    public void startTask(){
        while (running){
            doSomething();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(interval * 1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                //Handle the exception.
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopTask(){
        this.running = false;
    }

    public void setInterval(int newInterval){
        this.interval = newInterval;
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach, as you can see, is that setInterval() is not immediately effective. It takes effect only after a previous sleep() has completed.

Since my use case allows the end user to set the interval in fixed steps (of 1 second - from 1 to 60 seconds), I modified the implementation to sleep within a loop; and check for the new interval value every second as follows:

**Snippet2:**

```
public class PeriodicTask {

    private boolean running = true;
    private int interval = 5;
    private int loopCounter = 0;

    public void startTask(){
        while (running){
            doSomething();
            try{
                while(loopCounter < interval) {
                    Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                    loopCounter ++;
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                //Handle the exception.
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopTask(){
        this.running = false;
    }

    public void setInterval(int newInterval){
        synchronized (this) {
            this.interval = newInterval;
            if(newInterval < loopCounter){
                loopCounter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a reason to not use this approach?

I recently came across the `interrupt()` method for this purpose. But, I couldn't exactly figure out how to use it. For one, the interrupt method, unlike the sleep method is not `static`. So, what `Thread` do I interrupt?

```
public void setInterval(int newInterval){
        this.interval = newInterval;
        //What thread do I call interrupt() on?
    }
```

Secondly, if I do succeed in interrupting the sleeping `Thread`, I believe the `catch` block for the `InterruptedException` will be executed. However, I will need to call the `startTask()` again at this point. I am confused regarding the termination of this recursion. I have gone through several questions on SO regarding the use of interrupt(), but couldn't figure out anything that helps me.

Any pointers?

---

### EDIT- More details on exact requirement:

MY app fetches some values using a REST call every few seconds. The update interval is configurable by the user.

Now, say the update interval has been set to 60 seconds. Snippet1 I posted would work (incorrectly) as follows:

- Thread goes to sleep for 60 seconds.
- Now, lets say user changes the update interval to 5 seconds. The thread is still sleeping.
- The `PeriodicTask` would see the new update interval only after the 60 seconds have expired.

The exact requirement is that the new update intervals should be effective immediately (or at least no later than 1 second after being set - since that is what the user is likely to perceive anyway).

My Snippet2 and Snippet3 are attempts at achieving this requirement.

Comment: @Martin James, That's it! The good old wait()/notify() did the trick for me. I wonder how I've been coding Java all these years without ever having come across this!! Could you move this comment to an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Thread sleep/interrupt is just as old as wait/notify.

Comment: Sorry to pass by after everybody but have you considered using Timers? I'm sure it exists in Android as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIRC, in Java you can object.wait() with a timeout. Is this not what you want? If you want to change the timeout from another thread, change some 'waitValue' variable and notify(). The thread will then 'immediately' run and then wait again with the new timeout value. No explicit sleep required.

Comment: This solved the problem. Awarding it as accepted. Posted my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8727885/570930

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727761/570930) answer helped me do the job. Posting some code on how I achieved it. Of particular importance are `startTask()` and `setInterval()`.

```
public class PeriodicTask {

    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private volatile int interval = 5;
    private final Object lockObj = new Object();

    public void startTask() {
        while (running) {
            doSomething();
            synchronized (lockObj) {
                try{
                    lockObj.wait(interval * 1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    //Handle Exception
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopTask() {
        this.running = false;
    }

    public void setInterval(int newInterval) {
        synchronized (lockObj) {
            this.interval = newInterval;
            lockObj.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick note: running is still not correctly synchronized, and, consider using a lock object rather than than the instance object.  The usual argument is that the monitor for PeriodicTask could be held by something else causing you to block before you get to your wait.

Comment: Thanks yet again. I edited the post to add the `volatile` keyword to the variable declarations. By "lock objects", do you mean I create a single "dummy" object (perhaps an instance of `Object`), and synchronize with this object?

Comment: yes, it would be like 'private final Object lock = new Object();' and then you would use 'synchronized(lock)'.

Comment: Has wait(interval) a similar "precision" to sleep(interval)? If so, this seem a much better solution to sleep() + interrupt(), allowing to control exactly what is interrupted (my own issue).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not clear on what you really want to do.  Is you goal to stop the thread that is running the loop in PeriodicTask or do you just want to break the loop and allow the thread to continue?  If you just want to break the loop but allow the thread to continue, consider the following example:

```
public class ThreadStopExample {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        final PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask ();
        Thread t = new Thread ( new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                System.out.println ( Thread.currentThread ().getName () 
                    + " starting" );
                task.startTask ();
                System.out.println ( Thread.currentThread ().getName ()
                    + " done with the periodic task" );
            }
        } );
        t.start ();
        Thread.sleep ( 12000 );
        task.setInterval ( 1 );
        Thread.sleep ( 3000 );
        task.stopTask ();
    }

    static class PeriodicTask {

        private volatile boolean running = true;
        private volatile int interval = 5;

        public void startTask () {
            running = true;
            while ( running ) {
                doSomething ();
                try {
                    int count = 0;
                    while ( running && count++ < interval ) {
                        Thread.sleep ( 1000 );
                    }
                } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    Thread.currentThread ().interrupt ();
                    running = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void stopTask () {
            running = false;
        }

        public void setInterval ( int newInterval ) {
            interval = newInterval;
        }

        private void doSomething () {
            System.out.println ( "[" + Thread.currentThread ().getName () 
                + "] Interval: " + interval );
        }
    }
}
```

This is very similar to your existing code.  Note the volatile fields to ensure correct synchronization between the thread running the PeriodicTask loop and the main thread that attempts to change the interval and to stop the task (see [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/) for links to more information on the memory model for java).  As you can see, the thread that works with the PeriodicTask instance continues after the call to stop the task.  Also, note that PeriodicTask will call interrupt on the current thread when it receives the interrupted exception.  This ensures that the interrupt flag is set on the current thread so that any outer code is able to see the interrupt and react appropriately, e.g. instead of printing done, the thread running PeriodicTask may have checked the interrupt status of itself and done something interesting.

If your goal is to stop the thread itself, then you may want to have PeriodicTask extend Thread, which is not recommended unless you have a good reason to do so, or, have PeriodicTask implement Runnable.  Consider the next example:

```
public class ThreadStopExample2 {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        final PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask ();
        Thread t = new Thread ( task );
        t.start ();
        Thread.sleep ( 12000 );
        task.setInterval ( 1 );
        Thread.sleep ( 3000 );
        t.interrupt ();
    }

    static class PeriodicTask implements Runnable {

        private volatile int interval = 5;

        @Override
        public void run () {
            while ( true ) {
                doSomething ();
                try {
                    int count = 0;
                    while ( count++ < interval ) {
                        Thread.sleep ( 1000 );
                    }
                } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    Thread.currentThread ().interrupt ();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void setInterval ( int newInterval ) {
            interval = newInterval;
        }

        private void doSomething () {
            System.out.println ( "[" + Thread.currentThread ().getName () 
               + "] Interval: " + interval );
        }
    }
}
```

Here, PeriodicTask sits in a busy loop until the thread running it is interrupted.  The interrupt is used to signal the PeriodicTask to exit the loop, which then allows the thread to complete by falling through the end of the run method.

Regarding your two explicit questions: no, I don't see any real problem with using PeriodicTask the way you are if you aren't intending to control the executing thread, e.g. maybe the instance of PeriodicTask is run by a thread in a pool (but do be sure to fix your code to be correctly synchronized), and, when using interrupt you call it on the instance of the thread that you want to interrupt.  How you get a reference to that thread is dependent on your system.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation; and for pointing out the `volatile` keyword on the loop counter and flag. I edited my question to explain my exact requirement. I am not explicitly creating a `Thread` at all (nor implementing `Runnable`). When user chooses to "stop" the UI, I simply set `running` flag to `false`. The problem is when user modifies the update interval. This is where I need to play around with the sleeping threads etc.

Answer (score 1):

You call `interrupt()` on the thread that's sleeping and it will throw an `InterruptedException` which you handle in your catch block. Then you have your new interval and you can loop around and go back to sleep. If you catch and handle the `InterruptedException` nothing further happens.

Let me provide a couple of links of examples of creating and interrupting threads, as from your comments you seem to be missing some important ideas. Please review these carefully and then you should understand the standard way to do what you are asking for.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: That's what I'm getting confused with: if I use the `static Thread.sleep()` method to go to sleep, how do I get a handle to a `Thread` object in order to `interrupt()` it?

Comment: You have to get a handle to the `Thread` when you create it and put it somewhere so that you can call `interrupt()` on it. The `Thread` is just an object like anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. But isn't that forcing me to subclass Thread just because I want to interrupt it later? What about the implicit thread that I put to sleep using Thread.sleep()? How do I get to it (since that is the one I need to interrupt anyway)? Note that I am also looking for opinions on how the interrupt() approach compares with my earlier solution.

Comment: I expanded my answer with some links to the Java tutorials that explain this stuff. Hopefully this should help you see what I'm talking about.

Comment: +1 for the links. I've been coding in Java for 6 years now without having even this basic understanding of Thread interruption!

Comment: Yeah, it's funny how you can miss certain things that you don't use. I'm actually a bit behind the times. I have been programming in Java since it first came out and the Generics still seem new to me and I have not even looked into Java 7.

Comment: This answer is correct.  However, note that, in many cases such as java.util.concurrent, interrupt() is used to interrupt and _stop_ a long running process, _not_ to "wake it up".  You should note this in your comments.  Alternatively, you could consider a wait/notify with a timeout.

Comment: @user949300, `wait`/`notify` indeed was *the* solution to my problem. Your comment got my upvote. Thanks!