# Waking up a thread in Java with sleep method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithreading in Java so excuse me for this question
Is there any way to wake up a sleeping thread who was slept by calling the sleep(timeout) method and before that timeout expires ? for example waking him up for some event

Thank you

I have tried this code handling my event to manually sleep/wakeup the thread but it does not work : the thread sleeps but can not resume

```
              try {
             if(sleepMyThread){

            myThread.sleep(100000);
            sleepMyThread = false;
              }
             else{
            myThread.interrupt();
            sleepMyThread = true;
              }
          }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This looks similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708473/waking-up-a-sleeping-thread-interrupt-versus-splitting-the-sleep-into-mult

Comment: @codeNinja - it does, but >>this<< Question expresses the problem without 2 screenfulls of the OP's dubious code and life story :-)

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation of `sleep` method carefully. It clearly states - method throws `InterruptedException`. So, you can wake up a sleeping thread by interrupting that thread. However, that is not the way to send events to thread. For sending events (well ... not really event based mechanism is available in core java) you should use a `wait` - `notify` mechanism.

Comment: Do you mean that calling the method interrupt wakes up thread from sleep method ?

Comment: try {
      if(sleepMyThread){
      
                              myThread.sleep(100000);
                                sleepMyThread = false;
     }
     else{
                                               myThread.interrupt();
                                  sleepMyThread  =  true;
    }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Call the `interrupt()` method on your thread. It will throw an `InterruptedException` so make sure you handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can interrupt, catch the interrupt exception and loop through it again. A good simple tutorial is here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html